# Angular ng-click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a modal with the JavaScript UI of Bootstrap. Here I have any difficulties while opening a modal with JavaScript.

Here are the HTML source code which is working fine when I'm clicking on the button.

```
<div ng-controller="ModalNotificationCtrl" >

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="notificationContent">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">close</button>
    </div>
  </script>

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()" id="openbutt">Open me!</button>
</div>
```

I want to remove the button because I want to open the modal with JavaScript.

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-if="isModelShown">
 <div class="modal-header">
   <h3 class="modal-title">title</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <p>content</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">close</button>
 </div>
</div>

$scope.isModelShown = true
```